# Probability that $w^{x} + w^{y} + w^{z} = 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A dice is rolled 3 times and $(x,y,z)$ are obtained on dice then what would be probability that $w^{x} + w^{y} + w^{z} = 0$ where $w$ is cube root of unity and $w$ is **not** $1$

Since $$w + w^2 + w^3 = 1$$ 
I can get 3 values of $(x,y,z)$

- $(1,2,3)$
- $(2,3,4)$
- $(4,5,6)$

Now probability should be $$P(E)=\frac{3}{6.6.6}.3$$ extra $3$ in numerator since there would also be 3 repetition, what's wrong here?

Comment: Surely $w+w^2+w^3=0$? Also what about $(1,2,6)$, $(1,3,5)$, ... There are 8 combinations of $x,y,z$ that give $w+w^2+w^3=0$ and 6 permutations of each of them giving a probability of $(8\times 6)/6^3=2/9$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing values of $(x,y,z)$ which would make the equation satisfied. For example, $w^1+w^2+w^6=0$. In addition, there should be an extra $6$, instead of an extra $3$, in the numerator to account for the repetition, since there are $6$ permutations of the list $(x,y,z)$.

Here is a simpler way to think about it:

Since $w^x=w^{x+3}$, only the outcome of each die (mod $3$) matters, so it is equivalent think of this as rolling three fair 3-sided dice numbered $0,1,2$. Then, the the sum $w^x+w^y+w^z$ will be zero if and only if $(x,y,z)$ is some permutation of $(0,1,2)$. There are $6$ such permutations, and $3^3$ possible rolls, so the probability of success is $\frac{6}{27}=\frac{2}9$.